# Blank line at the top of a ghost blog

Tags: ghost-blog

I've got the blogging software [Ghost 0.4.2](http://blog.ghost.org/ghost-0-4-2-maintenance-release/) installed on a DigitalOcean droplet using one of their images.

The issue I have is that when I create a new blog entry, the top line of text I create is invisible to me, but turns up in the preview panel on the right hand side.

I've googled this and I can't see it's a reported issue.

I'm using Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path may be different but the problem seems to be with Chrome, and the style tag for the editor.hbs file.

`/var/www/ghost/core/server/views/editor.hbs`

And change the single occurrence of

```
padding:15px
```

to

```
padding:50px
```

and then restart

```
service ghost restart
```

which fixes it for me.  Thanks to NotNotJosh